Cannot build android project. Getting: "Failed to transform core-1.8.0-beta01.aar. This should not happen under normal circumstances"
I have a pure android java-based project.
Locally in android studio, everything is building properly.
Now, I'm trying to set a jenkins android build machine, based on ubuntu 24.04, and openjdk-17-jdk and tried with multiple different commandlinetools for linux, but always the same result.
Here is the output:
> Task :clean UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:clean
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues
> Task :app:generateDebugResources
> Task :app:dataBindingTriggerDebug
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata
> Task :app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest
> Task :app:packageDebugResources
> Task :app:parseDebugLocalResources
> Task :app:processDebugManifest
> Task :app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
> Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage
AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: /var/lib/jenkins/.gradle/caches/8.9/transforms/e7f7d367b1013ddf63765ee5a63a746d/transformed/aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-linux/aapt2: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: /var/lib/jenkins/.gradle/caches/8.9/transforms/e7f7d367b1013ddf63765ee5a63a746d/transformed/aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-linux/aapt2: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-linux Daemon #2: Unexpected error output: /var/lib/jenkins/.gradle/caches/8.9/transforms/e7f7d367b1013ddf63765ee5a63a746d/transformed/aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-linux/aapt2: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-linux Daemon #3: Unexpected error output: /var/lib/jenkins/.gradle/caches/8.9/transforms/e7f7d367b1013ddf63765ee5a63a746d/transformed/aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-linux/aapt2: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-linux Daemon #4: Unexpected error output: /var/lib/jenkins/.gradle/caches/8.9/transforms/e7f7d367b1013ddf63765ee5a63a746d/transformed/aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-linux/aapt2: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-linux Daemon #5: Unexpected error output: /var/lib/jenkins/.gradle/caches/8.9/transforms/e7f7d367b1013ddf63765ee5a63a746d/transformed/aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-linux/aapt2: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-linux Daemon #6: Unexpected error output: /var/lib/jenkins/.gradle/caches/8.9/transforms/e7f7d367b1013ddf63765ee5a63a746d/transformed/aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-linux/aapt2: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform imagepicker-1.13.1.aar (com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:imagepicker:1.13.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /var/lib/jenkins/.gradle/caches/8.9/transforms/d1ca8ff150e770cd7582ed25a69395f8/transformed/jetified-imagepicker-1.13.1.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-linux Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform paymentsheet-20.2.1.aar (com.stripe:paymentsheet:20.2.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /var/lib/jenkins/.gradle/caches/8.9/transforms/5416b880d979e3c0972fdd37a241b05e/transformed/jetified-paymentsheet-20.2.1.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-linux Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform stripe-3ds2-android-6.1.5.aar (com.stripe:stripe-3ds2-android:6.1.5) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /var/lib/jenkins/.gradle/caches/8.9/transforms/0488699c74001b9937d7f31e9e69a3f7/transformed/jetified-stripe-3ds2-android-6.1.5.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-linux Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform spectrum-0.7.1.aar (com.thebluealliance:spectrum:0.7.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /var/lib/jenkins/.gradle/caches/8.9/transforms/354df88369f100a10c55b402691b20f9/transformed/jetified-spectrum-0.7.1.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-linux Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform appcompat-1.4.1.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /var/lib/jenkins/.gradle/caches/8.9/transforms/cf435961ef31e791a75fc5030a7a9111/transformed/appcompat-1.4.1.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-linux Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform play-services-base-18.0.1.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.0.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /var/lib/jenkins/.gradle/caches/8.9/transforms/b429800d4ecd8a6550f78aa93cf04d15/transformed/jetified-play-services-base-18.0.1.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-linux Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.8.0-beta01.aar (androidx.core:core:1.8.0-beta01) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /var/lib/jenkins/.gradle/caches/8.9/transforms/06475e993092c680d8d1872746561ff7/transformed/core-1.8.0-beta01.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-linux Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at .

BUILD FAILED in 23shttps://help.gradle.org

"This should not happen" is a beautiful one :D
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

At the start of the error log you have "AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: /var/lib/jenkins/.gradle/caches/8.9/transforms/e7f7d367b1013ddf63765ee5a63a746d/transformed/aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-linux/aapt2: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected"
